# Initializing values in OleCreatePropertyFrame for web capture pin properties

Tags: winapi, directshow

Has anyone been able to fully initialize the values in the OleCreatePropertyFrame() menu when using it to set web capture pin properties?

As long as one does not re "Moniker" the "IBaseFilter *pSrc", the "IAMStreamConfig *pConfig" getFormat() value is maintained (one can release and rebuild the FilterGraph without changing the current configuration).

However, the OleCreatePropertyFrame() menu always seems to display the lowest format height for the current format width, and the maximum frame rate allowed.
This behavior can be seen in AMcap as well as in other small examples.

Has anyone figure how to get OleCreatePropertyFrame() to simply display the exact current format?

Comment: What are all the  properties you want? Is it about the video?

Comment: Yes it is about video .. Filter capture pin properties include format (ie mjpg,yuy2), format resolution (x,y pixel width), and frame rate.  capture pin properties are different from basic filter properties (ie exposure time, etc)